# Gap between divs on IE and Firefox

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, firefox

I know this is a common problem, but one for which the solutions I've found don't seem to be working.

There's a gap between the header and content div in IE / Firefox on this website, but it's fine on Chrome.  Can anyone suggest what may be causing it?

http://www.britainsbiggestcurryparty.org/

It's not a padding issue, and it doesn't seem to be a font size issue.  I've tried removing all margins globally and that doesn't work either.  driving me a little bit nuts!

Any suggestions would be gratefully received

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's the default 16px of top/bottom margin on `<ul>` and `<ol>` elements that's causing the discrepancy, all you need to do is remove the margins:

```
nav ul {
list-style: none;
margin: 0;
}
```

You should also look into using a [CSS reset](http://cssreset.com) to avoid the browsers default styles

Answer (score -1):

You just can set margin: 0; it will solve your problem